# Tagify removes the tag but still remains in the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagify

I have aproblem with tagify. When I remove a tag (using tag cross), visually the tag is removed from the text area but then it is passed as a parameter via ajax. For example, if I have the following text:

```
Vito hello
```

and `Vito` is a tag, if I delete it, visually only `hello` remains but still if I send the text taking the text area via jquery still it considers me the text `Vito hello`.

What is the problem?

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>BigMouth v1.0</title>
        <script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui.min.css">
        <script src="../jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../tagify"></script>
        <script src="../tagify.polyfills.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../tagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="../bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap.css">
       
 

    <script>
        function ShareData(){

 
            let datepicker = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
            let oggetto = document.getElementById("oggetto").value;
            let descrizione = document.getElementById("descrizione").value;
            
            // list_added_people is a global variable

 
            const ids = list_added_people.map(o => o.id)
            // remove duplicates
            const filtered = list_added_people.filter(({ id }, index) => !ids.includes(id, index + 1))


            let json_form = { 'date': datepicker, 'oggetto': oggetto, 'descrizione': descrizione, 'people': filtered };

            ipcRenderer.send('insert_event', JSON.stringify(json_form));
        

 


        }

 
    </script>
        

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="messages"></div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="id_people"></div>
  
        
        <div class="container">
            <form id="myForm" action="#"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="row" id="title_area">
                        <h1>Inserisci evento:</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="date_area">
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Data: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row" id="object_area">
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Oggetto: <input type="text" id="oggetto"  style=" width:50%"></p>
                        </div>                
                    </div>  

                    <div class="row" id="description_area">
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Descrizione:</p>
                            <textarea id = "descrizione" name='mix'></textarea>
                        </div>                
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row" id="buttons_area">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">Salva</button>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <button type="button" id = "prova" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Cancella</button>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>    
                    <button onclick="ShareData()">ShareData</button>
                </div>      
            </form>
        </div>     
            
            
        </div>
        


        <style>

            #date_area{
                margin-top: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            #object_area{
                margin-top: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            #description_area{
                margin-top: 50px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

    
            #buttons_area{
                margin-top: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

 
            .delete_btn_area{
                margin-left: 30px;
            }
        </style>

        <script>

            Array.prototype.containsArray = function (val) {
                var hash = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                    hash[this[i]] = i;
                }
                return hash.hasOwnProperty(val);
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){ 

                var whitelist_1;
                list_added_people = []
            
                // AGGIUNGE LE PERSONE SALVATE IN DB NEL TAGGIFY
                ipcRenderer.send('get_people', "ciao backend");
                window.api.receivePeople((data) => {
                    let people = JSON.parse(data)
                   
                    for(i in people){
                        whitelist_1.push({ value: people[i]['id'], text: people[i]['name'] + " " + people[i]['surname'], title: people[i]['name'] + " " + people[i]['surname'] })
                    }
                })
               
               
                
                $( function() {
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
                });

                // Define two types of whitelists, each used for the dropdown suggestions menu,
                // depending on the prefix pattern typed (@/#). See settings below.
                var whitelist_1 = [
                    { value: 100, text: 'kenny', title: 'Kenny McCormick' },
                    { value: 1000, text: 'Mr. Mackey', title: "M'Kay" }
                ]

                // Second whitelist, which is shown only when starting to type "#".
                // Thiw whitelist is the most simple one possible.
                whitelist_2 = ['Homer simpson', 'Marge simpson', 'Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie', 'Mr. Burns', 'Ned', 'Milhouse', 'Moe'];


                // initialize Tagify
                var input = document.querySelector('[name=mix]'),
                // init Tagify script on the above inputs
                tagify = new Tagify(input, {
                //  mixTagsInterpolator: ["{{", "}}"],
                    mode: 'mix',  // <--  Enable mixed-content
                    pattern: /@|#/,  // <--  Text starting with @ or # (if single, String can be used here)
                    tagTextProp: 'text',  // <-- the default property (from whitelist item) for the text to be rendered in a tag element.
                    // Array for initial interpolation, which allows only these tags to be used
                    whitelist: whitelist_1.concat(whitelist_2).map(function(item){
                        return typeof item == 'string' ? {value:item} : item
                    }),
                    dropdown : {
                        enabled: 1,
                        position: 'text', // <-- render the suggestions list next to the typed text ("caret")
                        mapValueTo: 'text', // <-- similar to above "tagTextProp" setting, but for the dropdown items
                        highlightFirst: true  // automatically highlights first sugegstion item in the dropdown
                    },
                    duplicates: true,
                    callbacks: {
                        add: console.log,  // callback when adding a tag
                        remove: console.log   // callback when removing a tag
                    }
                })


                // A good place to pull server suggestion list accoring to the prefix/value
                tagify.on('input', function(e){
                    var prefix = e.detail.prefix;

                    // first, clean the whitlist array, because the below code, while not, might be async,
                    // therefore it should be up to you to decide WHEN to render the suggestions dropdown
                    // tagify.settings.whitelist.length = 0;

                    if( prefix ){
                        if( prefix == '@' )
                            tagify.whitelist = whitelist_1;

                        if( prefix == '#' )
                            tagify.whitelist = whitelist_2;

                        if( e.detail.value.length > 1 )
                            tagify.dropdown.show(e.detail.value);
                    }

                console.log( tagify.value )
                console.log('mix-mode "input" event value: ', e.detail)
                })

                tagify.on('add', function(e){

                    let name = e.detail.data.text
                    let id = e.detail.data.value
                    console.log(list_added_people)
                    var flag = 0

      
                    list_added_people.push({ id: id, title: name })

                    
                })

                tagify.on('remove', function(e){
                    let id_deleted_person = e.detail.data.value
          
                    console.log("---")
                    console.log(e)
                    console.log(list_added_people)
                    var keyToFind = id_deleted_person;
                    var person_to_delete = -1;
                    for (var i in list_added_people) {
                        if (list_added_people[i].id == keyToFind) {
                            person_to_delete = i
                            break; // If you want to break out of the loop once you've found a match
                        }
                    }
                    if (person_to_delete != -1) {
                        list_added_people.splice(person_to_delete, 1)
                        console.log(list_added_people)
                    }
 
                    //list_added_people = list_added_people.filter(e => e !== id_deleted_person)
                })
            })
        </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need to see the code which demonstrates this issue. Also - ensure that you're reading the value of the input at the correct point, ie. *right before you make the request*, not when the page loads.

Comment: It looks like you're not referencing the tagify library correctly. There should be a filename at the end of this path, not the entire folder  `<script src="../tagify"></script>`

Comment: I added <script src="../tagify.js"></script> but nothing changed